# Why is this OpenGL 3 vertex shader very slow?

Tags: performance, opengl, glsl, shader

I have the following vertex shader:

```
#version 150

in vec4 position;
in vec2 texture;
in int layer;

out vec2 pass_texture;
out float pass_layer;

uniform mat4 _modelToClipMatrix;
uniform float layerDepth[255];

void main (void)
{
    gl_Position = _modelToClipMatrix*vec4(position.xy,layerDepth[layer]/255,position.w);
    // gl_Position = _modelToClipMatrix*position;
    pass_layer = float(layer);
    pass_texture = texture;
}
```

When I use it the way it is here, my frame rate is about 7 FPS. If I use the second line (which is commented out) instead of the first, my frame rate jumps to about 50 FPS. It seems that the array lookup is the big problem here. Why is it so terribly slow? And how can I improve performance while keeping functionality?

My hardware is a ATI Radeon HD 4670 256 MB (iMac 2010 model).

My vertex structure looks like:

```
typedef struct
{
    floatVector2 position; //2*4=8
    uByteVector2 textureCoordinate; //2*1=2
    GLubyte layer; //1
} PCBVertex;
```

and I set op the buffer in the following way:

```
glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)positionAttribute, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(PCBVertex), (const GLvoid *)offsetof(PCBVertex, position));
glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)textureAttribute, 2, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_FALSE, sizeof(PCBVertex), (const GLvoid *)offsetof(PCBVertex, textureCoordinate));
glVertexAttribIPointer(layerAttribute, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sizeof(PCBVertex), (const GLvoid *)offsetof(PCBVertex, layer));
```

*Some background information:*
I'm working on a drawing package. The user can draw on multiple layers. One layer is active at a time and it's drawn front-most. He can also "flip" the layers, as if looking from the other side. I figured it would be inefficient to update all vertices when the layer order changes, so I give each vertex a layer number and lookup its current position in the uniform (I only send x and y as position data). Also, as a side note: the fragment shader uses the same layer number to determine the color, using a uniform array as well.

Comment: Have you tried reducing the number of layers to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: A 1-D texture lookup might be faster than an array uniform.

Comment: Also, if your vertices are sorted prior to the layer order lookup, the pipeline might doing Z-order clipping and not invoking the fragment shader for obscured objects.  Whereas when you adjust the order, you may be drawing back to front, and having to render all pixels multiple times.

Comment: @Ben: That seems *highly* unlikely.

Comment: We need more information. For example, how are you passing these attribute values? Particularly the `layer` input.

Comment: Did it fall back to software mode? Also, what is GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS?

Comment: No answer, but I have almost exactly the same problem. See http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/178942-Drastic-performance-drop-with-random-index?p=1242135#post1242135
It doesn't look like it is the index operation that is slow, it is when you index with a parameter that is varying. Try to change "layer" into a constant, just to confirm if this is the problem.

Comment: What if you explicitly calculate and load `uniform float layerz[255]` for `layerDepth[layer]/255.0f` and set `position.z = layerz[layer]` prior to matrix multiplication? It's semantically equivalent, but the shader compiler *might* generate more efficient code.

Comment: Thanks for your replies so far. I've been playing around a bit and it seems to have something to do with the uniform(s) being to big. When I reduce the size to 100, it all runs very smooth. I also noticed that in the 255-size case the CPU usage is 100%, so perhaps the vertex shader was running on the CPU. In the 100-size case all color is lost, so the pass_layer to the fragment shader goes wrong there.

Comment: GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS is 4096, as specified by Apple. I don't know how to request the value at runtime, as I'm very new to OpenGL.

Comment: @RemcoPoelstra Apple lies then, otherwise it shouldn't be the problem. That's not very surprising however, ATI's drivers lie about GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS as well. Terribly inconvenient. `texelFetch`ing from a 1D texture could be an idea perhaps

Comment: Yes, I'm going to try that, but I've never used textures, so it will take a while before I figured out how to use them.

Comment: Have you tried using UBOs instead? The minimum size (GL_MAX_UNIFORM_BLOCK_SIZE) is 16384 bytes according to the spec. I had a similar problem, and UBOs solved it for me.

Comment: No, I ended up using a 1D texture which works like charm

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the line

```
gl_Position = _modelToClipMatrix*vec4(position.xy,layerDepth[layer]/255,position.w);
```

from your shader the uniform `float layerDepth[255];` will become unused. That means the compiler will optimize it away.

Further more, the `layerAttribute` location will become -1, preventing any data transfers for this attrib pointer.